# Create new row from 2 CSVs based on match from one column

Tags: powershell, csv, import, scripting

I'm trying to do the following with PowerShell:

1. Compare a specific value from one column in CSV #1 against CSV #2.
2. If it matches on that specific value, then combine the entire row (except that value that it matched to prevent duplicate values) from that match in one new row in a new CSV file with or without headers

For example: Match on column 'animal'

CSV #1:

```
animal, name, age
dog, spot, 5
cat, whiskers, 3
iguana, lizzy, 1
```

CSV #2:

```
animal, color, eyes
fish, yellow, 2
dog, brown, 2
```

Result: new file CSV #3 below

```
dog, spot, 5, brown, 2
```

I tried with `Import-Csv` for CSV #1, but I am having issues iterating through CSV #2 using an `if -match` statement...

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the first CSV once and check whether the second CSV contains the same animal. If so, create a new `PsCustomObject` with the desired properties and finally convert the object to CSV:

```
$csv1 = 
@'
animal, name, age
dog, spot, 5
cat, whiskers, 3
iguana, lizzy, 1
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$csv2 = 
@'
animal, color, eyes
fish, yellow, 2
dog, brown, 2
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$csv1 | ForEach-Object  {
    $csv1Entity = $_
    $csv2Entity = $csv2 | where animal -eq $csv1Entity.animal
    if ($csv2Entity)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            animal = $csv1Entity.animal
            name = $csv1Entity.name
            age = $csv1Entity.age
            color = $csv2Entity.color
            eyes = $csv2Entity.eyes
        }
    }
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

---

**Output:**

```
"animal","name","age","color","eyes"
"dog","spot","5","brown","2"
```